# Как исправить дублированную прорисовку?

Tags: python, turtle

Код представляет из себя многократное построение звёздочек с увеличением вершин. Проблема заключается в том, что каждое построение проходит и код дублирует фигуру. Как это исправить? Вот код:

```
import turtle

a = turtle.Turtle()


def starFILL(n, length):
    a.begin_fill()
    sq(n, length)
    a.end_fill()


def sq(n, length):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        for i in range(n):
            a.forward(length)
            angle = n // 2 * 360 / n
            a.left(angle)


for j in range(1, 200, 7):
    a.speed(50)
    sq(j, 250)
    starFILL(j, 250)
    a.reset()

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно убрать вызов `sq`в вашем цикле.

```
for j in range(1, 200, 7):
    a.speed(50)
    # тут был вызов
    starFILL(j, 250)
    a.reset()
```